# Snap failing with error: Failed to install GPG key

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a snap for my ROS package but it fails with the following error even though `dirmngr` is installed.

```
Failed to install GPG key: Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.5dGB3qgLls/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.5dGB3qgLls/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr

Recommended resolution:
Verify any configured GPG keys.

Detailed information:
GPG key ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
GPG key server: keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

I really do not know how to verify configured GPG keys. How should I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364941/snap-failing-with-error:-failed-to-install-gpg-key/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-06**:
Is this ROS related? Not having `dirmngr` installed is a general Ubuntu problem.

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-11-06**:
This implies that you don't have `gnupg` installed, is that true? Your log is very clipped so it's impossible to know, but this gives the impression that you're running snapcraft without a build VM or a container where it manages the image. Are you using `--destructive-mode`, or building in Docker or something? Assuming so, install `gnupg` and you should be good.

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-11-08**:
I have just confirmed that I have gnupg installed (this is version 2.2.4). Any other ideas?

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-11-10**:
I am not using `--destructive-mode` or building in Docker either. How could I make sure I am using the necessary build VM? Is there any more information needed to work out this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve this problem after some misunderstanding about where `dirmgr` was installed. It turns out that this was only on my local machine rather than the VM used to build the `Snap`. The solution was therefore to run `snapcraft --debug` and then `apt install dirmngr -y`. After that, `snapcraft` runs sucessfully.

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2020-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0